# Elasticsearch: Approximate quantitative difference between insert and update performance

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

I have read many posts I could find here and on the internet internet on insert vs. updates but was unable to find any, even order of magnitude, quantitative statements. Let's assume I do bulk update operations on 50% of my document fields, can I expect the performance vs. bulk index operations with data from all fields to be 80%, 50%, 20%, 10%, 1% of an insert? Just a rough number from experience would be very helpful.

Disclaimer: I understand that inserts are preferable in terms of performance but often there's a difficult trade-off between access/query performance/complexity and insert performance, especially if you have data that you want to query in one place but individual components have different lifecycles. So in my case, I would probably be OK with a certain, even significant write performance hit to keep all other properties of my ES index ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a particular reason for this not being discussed commonly.
The update operation (add + delete) does not delete the document instantly. Instead, it marks the document as deleted by marking a bit. Therefore, the performance of document addition and document update is not very different.

However, once enough documents are marked deleted, the Lucene indexes are merged and deleted documents are completely removed. Until that time, the documents keep piling up as they do not free the space.

So, the only performance indicator that is considered is the performance of search (as it is effected in terms of results and in terms of time complexity as well).

More on document merging [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/lucenes-handling-of-deleted-documents).

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand why would there be a delete in my case if I send an update with a partial document (as part of a bulk operation)?

Comment: By default, the Elastic search does not support update operation. So, even you are updating the documents partially (only some fields are being updated), the elastic is completely reindexing the document. In short, elastic will make use of delete if you modify any filed of the index document. I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, that helps. But you don't have a rough, approximate quantitative difference between add and delete + add?

Comment: Unfortunately, No. But if you perform some kind of quantitative analysis, I will be more than happy to discuss.